# How to Connect Two Switches to Asus RT-AC88U Router

Tags: networking, router, switch

I currently have the following networking configuration in my office.

Clients connected to a switch connected into a router. As per the details and image below.

- Router: ASUS RT-AC88U
- Switch: TP LINK un-managed Gigabit Ethernet Switch TL-SG1024

[current network configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkIKS.png)

And this works completely fine. No issues at all.

However, when I connect a secondary switch with some more clients either to the first switch (option 1) or directly to the router (option 2). As per the image and details below.

- Router: ASUS RT-AC88U
- Switch 1: TP LINK un-managed Gigabit Ethernet Switch TL-SG1024
- Switch 2: TP LINK un-managed Gigabit Ethernet Switch TL-SG1024

[proposed network config options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTvn7.png)

All the clients get kicked off the network and cannot re-establish connection. 
Does anyone have any idea why this may be occurring?

Additional info...

- All wireless clients and single clients connected directly to the LAN ports on the router still remain connected to the network when the switch arrangement is modified.

Comment: Can you describe "getting kicked off the network"? Do you see any change on the 1st switch's LEDs? Can clients on switch 1 reach those on switch 2? Either one of your options should work fine (though definitely _not both at once_).

Comment: @grawity "getting kicked off the network" - All clients connected via either switch just loose connection to the router. All LEDS on both switches remain un-effected (are all green indicating connection) when the arrangement is changed. Not sure how I can check if the clients on both switches can reach each other or not when they are not connected to the router. Can you advise?

Comment: Connect everything according to "option 1", then just try to ping computer 1 from computer 5, or similar. (Traffic within the same subnet does not go through a router.) If the computer was otherwise pingable before the connection, but stops being reachable afterwards, that might help with narrowing down the problem.

Comment: @grawity great i'll give this a go when everyone has left work for the day so I don't cause any server outages. In the interim is there anything else that comes to mind that could help isolate this issue?

Comment: With plain unmanaged switches? Aside from a network loop, no idea.

Comment: @grawity You could be write. Maybe it is a network loop. The second switch did work briefly at one point when connected to the first switch with only one client and that client having a static IP address assigned. Then stopped working as soon as a plumbing up more LAN cables (which I thought were clients) to the secondary switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving this issue by completing the following steps:

1. Setting the default gateway on the router to the router itself (192.168.0.1)

This partially fixed the issue and allowed the second switch to be connected into the system with only one client without any issues.

However, when the remaining clients were connected into the second switch. None of the clients on the second switch could connect to the network. The clients on the first switch remained unaffected.

1. Simply the problem by connecting one client at a time into the second switch.

This allowed me to identify that whenever a particular client was connected to the system. It would disconnect all users on the second switch. The client that was causing the issue in this case was a computer connected to the network that was crashed with an error message that was along the lines of ... "Please insert sandisk boot device". When this computer was restarted it no longer caused networking issues when connected to the system.

Answer (score -1):

I had issues installing the switch, but I managed to fix it:

1. Power off the modem
2. Power off the switch.

I think what resolved it, was powering off the switch and enabling the ports on the switch, one by one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).